# What is the difference between a parser and a State Machine?

Tags: java, scala, parsing

I want to write some code which parses emails, in a structure as follows:

```
Message-ID: <2252971.1075852681795>
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2001 05:56:08 -0700 (EST)
From: joebloggs@mail.net
To: jane@othermail.com, john@somemail.net
Subject: A subject goes here
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-From: Joe <joebloggs@mail.net>
X-To: Jane <jane@othermail.com>, John, Smith <john@somemail.net>
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \joebloggs\Inbox
X-Origin: Bloggs-J
X-FileName: joebloggs.pst

Hi, this is the information you were looking for...
Sincerely, 
Joe
```

I want to write some code which will parse this into (for example) an in-memory class, which I may then choose to write to disk in some sort of CSV format. Note that (for example) the `To:` field can be multi-line.

What I am wondering is, what **type** of problem am I looking at here? Is this an example of where writing a custom parser (and producing some sort of DSL) is useful, or am I better off modelling it as a State Machine with a big outer loop, some state and some functions which parse the input line by line, depending on what the current state is?

Languages I could write this in include Scala or Java..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is a software component that takes input data (frequently text) and builds a data structure.

*Parser* is not always a state machine but *state machine* is one possible way to implement a parser.

Regarding the second part of your question.

There are multiple parser libraries for scala and java. Most popular are [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki) and
[scala parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) (which I personally like more).

Also you can use [regular expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex), which is often faster to implement and easier way to parse something simple (btw, regexps internally are FSM).

For your case I'd probably go with regexps only. The structure of your input seems pretty straightforward, so just split it into sections and then parse each section separately.

Comment: What do you mean by "split it into sections"?

Comment: @jcm, I mean split the whole input into some smaller parts and them create individual smaller parsers for them. For example, you can split by first "\n\n" to separate text from headers. Then split by regexp [`/^[^:\s]+:/gm`](http://regexr.com/3cu33) to extract individual headers. Be creative! Often simpler means better.

Comment: How about if some of those lines can be multi-line? E.g. if the "To:" field contains many email addresses, and on multiple lines?

Comment: @jcm if you follow the link in my previous comment, you'll see that my example supports this case. But it was just an example, I can't possibly predict all peculiarities of your data. Start with something simple and try it against all your data to see how it goes.

Comment: Aivean - I've put my implementation on codereview stackexchange - if you could have a quick look and see if it's what you were thinking that would be great! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121740/is-there-a-cleaner-way-to-implement-this-email-text-parser